# Mover el contenido (Fragment) a la derecha al abrir el Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android

Trate de replicar un ejemplo encontrado aqui: [Move content to side in Drawer Layout Android](http://thetechnocafe.com/slide-content-to-side-in-drawer-layout-android/)

Pero no he podido replicarlo, este es mi codigo base, estoy usando el por defecto que da Android Studio, con algunas modificaciones pero no he podido hacer esto:

[image: Ejemplo moving content in Drawer Layout]

Este es mi codigo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.IDtoolbar);
    textView.setText("Proyectos");
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor, new FragmentProyectos()).commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.nav_proyectos) { fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor, new FragmentProyectos()).commit(); textView.setText("Proyectos"); }
    if (id == R.id.nav_contacto) { textView.setText("Contacto"); }
    if (id == R.id.nav_configuracion) { textView.setText("Configuracion"); }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
```

Como se puede ver esto lo único que hace es trasponerse al contenido, seguí el tutorial pero hay cosas que no entiendo muy bien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolví mi problema utilizando una libreria de Github: [Drawer-Behavior](https://github.com/shiburagi/Drawer-Behavior)

De esta manera pude generar el efecto deseado en mi Navigator Drawer